# Exporting the function which is inside an other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, currying

When the server starts I'm invoking a function:

```
server.listen(port, someFunction());
```

Inside of that function, I do some asynchronous operation to populate the data inside of an object.

I want to share whatever data is populated in that object with some other file.

```
someFunction(){
  someObject={
    //this gets populated with some asynchronous operation.
  }
  functionInsideFunction(){
   //I want this function to return someObject of the parent function
  }
 //This function can't return anything because it shows error, as this is 
  // being invoked at the server start.
}
```

I want to export the functionInsideFunction so that i can get the someData stored in someFunction in some other file!

So what should my approach be!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something like this :

```
const http = require('http')
// create your global object
let myObj = { }


var requestListener = function (req, res) {
  // use the object
  console.log(myObj);
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello, World!');
}

var server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(3000, function() { 
  console.log("Listening on port 3000")
  // fill the object here
  myObj = {
    'name': 'hello'
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.listen is expecting a callback function but someFunction doesn't seem to return anyone.

You could do `server.listen(port, someFunction.functionInsideFunction);` or `return functionInsideFunction() {}` in someFunction.